# Windows will not let me delete files made by my own user account

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-permissions

I have a bunch of leftover folders from when I downloaded an IDE and did not get removed when I uninstalled it. Today, I decided to remove these files, but found that every time I tried to delete the files, I would get an error saying that I needed permission from `Desktop-TXXXXX\[my user account name]` to delete them. I am signed into my user account, and I cannot remove them. Since my user account created them, I should be able to delete everything that was created by it.

The Error Message:
[image: My Error Message]

Permissions:
[image: The permissions]

Comment: According to the error message your user account does not have permissions to delete the folder.  You will have to use an Administrator account to delete the folder and/or modify the ACL for the folder and give your user account adequate permissions to delete the folder.

Comment: @Ramhound I am the administrator account

Comment: Also, @Ramhound both my user account and Administrators have "full access" to the folders

Comment: You will have to modify the ACL, make sure the user is the owner and/or Administrator group is the owner, and verify your user has permissions to delete the folder.  Any additional troubleshooting on the reason you are getting the prompt would require a screenshot of the ACL indicating what permissions the user has on the folder.  Edit your question instead of submitting comments.

Comment: With regards to your last comment, provide the ACL on the folder.  Make sure you show the complete list of permissions the user has on the folder.  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound i updated the post to show permissions

Comment: The standard fixes for this are to check that your account has ownership of the folder/files, and that the files are not in use or locked by the system or a driver.

Comment: @music2myear I have used a "Take Ownership" script that runs commands to take ownership of a file and it still did not fix anything. Also, it does not say it is locked or in use by anything

Comment: A, a script is nice, but did you go into the Security > Advanced dialog and take over ownership there? B, don't rely only on what the error message tells you. You should use one of the various tools available (such as ProcExp) to search for any locks on the file. For instance, I've found in the past that nVidia device drivers held locks on certain files in the Windows.Old directory, and I'd have to uninstall the drivers before I could delete this directory.

Comment: While you appear to be the owner of the file, your ACL indicates, you have zero permissions on the folder. However, I cannot tell which user, your displaying the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three most likely scenarios (in descending likelihood):

1) The file requires administrator permissions. Due to UAC controls in Windows, being logged in as an admin user doesn't give full administrative permissions. You may need to force the action with a UAC enabled application. The easiest way to do this would be to use an admin command prompt. Right click the start button (win 10) and select "Command Prompt (Admin)" or "Powershell (Admin)" and use commands there to delete the files. "del filename" or "Remove-item filename" (powershell)

2) The permissions on the file have actually changed. You may need to change the permissions on the file or even re-take ownership on the files before you can delete them.

3) You've had some sort of weird file lock issue on the machine. Try restarting the machine and trying again. It could be open in some file/application/process which may actually come back up automatically when you restart as well.

Edit: Try rebooting the machine to safe mode and deleting the file(s), this should release any file locks provided they aren't core OS or hostile (thanks to @Christopher Hostage for the suggestion).

Comment: In my experience, like #3, it was locked by a service or auto-started application.  In those cases, starting in Safe Mode was the only way to delete the file.